# Finding all Records where a particular Field has more than "n" number of characters in Oracle

Tags: schema, oracle10g

In Oracle, I am about to ALTER the structure of the table where I would be reducing the size of a certain field in a particular table. And, before I run an ALTER command, I would want to know the list of Records where the field has characters is more than the size that I am going to ALTER it to.

For instance, let us call my table - Employee. The field, Address_1 which is currently VARCHAR(60). I am about to modify this field as VARCHAR(40).

So, I need a list of all the records in the Employee table where the field Address_1 has 41 or more characters.

How can I find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from employee
where length(address_1) > 40;
```

Comment: Aaargh! Length! See, that is why you need to have StackOverflow. I tried with size for some bizarre reasons! Muppet me... Thanks Tony!